# How to Encrypt the Video file in SD-CARD in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native

I'm developing app using react native. basically this app do some encryption in devices internal memory such as videos and pic. Is this possible with react native.

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite broad, but you can access the filesystem with React Native by using [`react-native-fs`](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs). When you have filesystem access, it's just a matter of choosing which encryption algorithm you want to use. One possibility is [`react-native-aes`](https://github.com/tectiv3/react-native-aes).